# Inject class array

Tags: angular, angular2-injection

I have a MetaManager class:

```
@Injectable()
export class MetaManager{

    constructor(private handlers:Handler[]){
        console.log(handlers);
    }
}
```

this class needs a `Handler[]` to register as handlers. Than, when I get some metadata, I loop in my handlers array to see which one can handler my meta entry.

Having said that, problem is that I can't provide an array of class as config in main.ts, here is what I have tried (and what did not work):

Using String entry (with a `@Provide('HANDLERS')` annotation in MetaManager:

```
`bootstrap(AppComponent, [MetaManager,provide('HANDLERS', {useValue: [DebugHandler]}) ]);`
```

Using an interface to provide handlers:

```
export const HANDLERS: HandlerConfig = {handlers: [<Handler>DebugHandler]};

bootstrap(AppComponent, [MetaManager, provide(HandlerConfig, {useValue: HANDLERS}) ]);
```

Using a `Handler[]` class provider:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [MetaManager, provide(Handler[], [DebugHandler])]);
```

I want to provide a class array because `MetaManager` will need to have more than one Handler in the future, notification, error, etc...

EDIT:

Using multi provider gives me a `No provider for Array! (ApiService -> MetaManager -> Array)` Error:

meta-manager.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class MetaManager{

    constructor(private handlers:Handler[]){
        console.log(handlers);
    }
}
```

main.ts:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent,
    [   MetaManager,
        provide(Handler, {useClass: DebugHandler, multi: true}),
        provide(Handler, {useClass: NotificationHandler, multi: true})]);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `multi` attribute when registering your providers for the `Handler` class:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  MetaManager,
  provide(Handler, { useClass: DebugHandler, multi: true }),
  provide(Handler, { useClass: OtherHandler, multi: true })
]);
```

This way, you will be able to inject this way:

```
@Injectable()
export class MetaManager{
  constructor(@Inject(Handler) private handlers:Handler[]){
    console.log(handlers);
  }
}
```

Here is the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/UBIvWfOvAmo4XO2ohbID?p=preview.
This article could interest you:

- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular2/2015/11/23/multi-providers-in-angular-2.html

Comment: yes but what if I want to get every Handler registered? also, how to get every one of them?

Comment: The injected array contains all registered handlers. Perhaps I misunderstood your question. I updated my answer...

Comment: With the multi approach you need to register providers one by one. All the registered providers for this token will be provided as an array...

Comment: I just finished to try your example, I get a "no provider found for Array" error, seems like I don't get a Handler[]

Comment: Sorry for double comment, could not edit the last one. I edited my question to show you what I tried, and the exact error.

Comment: Yes, you're right I missed the `@Inject(Provider)` at the constructor level. It works with this. I updated my answer and added a plunkr...

Comment: Everything works fine, thank you :D Do I have a way to export a provider which provides this array? like a shorthand because I have to provide it in main.ts and in every spec.ts file using MetaManager

Comment: You could try useValue instead if useClass and return the array in it. The injection would demain the same...